# How to print Linux command On terminal

Tags: shell, terminal

At the time executing following command i get output as `i-56816733`

`str=$" $(wget -q -O- http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)"`
`echo $str`

But i want to print the whole command present in 'str' variable with $ sign on terminal as follows :-

`$(wget -q -O- http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)`

I want above output using 'echo' that how can i get ?

Comment: Next up, you will probably be wanting to read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: It's probably a typo in your question, but note that some shells (`bash`, at least) apply locale-based translations to strings of the form `$"..."`.

Answer (score 2):

Just use single quotes:

```
str='$(wget -q -O- http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)'
```

if you want interpolation there are two methods, you can append various single quoted strings:

```
str='$(mkdir'$1')'
```

or, you can escape the dollar signs you want literal and use double quotes:

```
str="\$(mkdir $1)"
```

Comment: it works but i unable to assign command line argument values to variable like for `mkdir $1` i unable to assign value to '$1'. How can i do ?